# VBA Multi dimensional Arrays used in multiple subs

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

Ok so I am still trying to work out Arrays, I am learning quickly but still have one specific area I cannot get round which is frustrating.

I am trying to reference an array across multiple subs and when clicking a button, I am populating the array with strings and integers (which works fine).

The array is Publically declared.

How do I get the multi array to work across the different subs? I have tried using paramArray myArray as variant but I'm doing something wrong and respectfully requesting help here.

Please don't get caught up in the detail of my code below (its probably wrong), the way im adding the data here and what the data is isn't the question, its about how im using the array.

Thanks

```
Public myArray()

Sub Main()
redim preserve myArray(10,5)
for z = 0 to 10
  for y = 0 to 5
     myArray(z,y) = 10 * Z + y
  Next y
Next z
End Sub

Sub Butn_Click()
  MsgBox myArray(0,1)
End sub

Sub testcode()
  MsgBox myArray(2,1)
end sub
```

Comment: `myArray(z,y) = myArray(z,y)` what is this to do? it will set empty to empty or is my array already populated?

Comment: I use the easy way (which not mot agree), I just have a dedicated module, named "Global_Var" and inside I declare my Global Variables, like  `Global myArray As Variant` (or whatever) then it is recognized from everywhere in the workbook.

Comment: The `Sub Butn_Click()` tells me that this is a worksheet code sheet, not a module code sheet. Worksheet code sheets are private by nature and you cannot declare a public variable such as you have done and expect the array to be available in other worksheet code sheets or module code sheets.

Comment: Thanks - I have sorted out my dodgy code from myArray(z,y) = myArray(z,y) in the example above to myArray(z,y) = 10 * Z + y. In my defence I did this without testing and guessed wrongly thinking it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried amending the code so it flowed to see if I can replicate the problem I was having... but it does work, typical!

Thank you for your responses!

```
Public myArray()

Sub Main()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub testcode()
  MsgBox myArray(2, 1)
End Sub

Sub testcode2()
    MsgBox myArray(0, 1)
    unload userform1
End Sub
```

The below code is in the userform code to ensure the button click works...

```
Sub Butn_Click()

  ReDim Preserve myArray(10, 5)
    For Z = 0 To 10
      For y = 0 To 5
         myArray(Z, y) = 10 * Z + y
      Next y
    Next Z

    Call testcode
    Call testcode2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
Public myArray()

Sub Main()
    ReDim Preserve myArray(10, 5)
    For Z = 0 To 10
      For y = 0 To 5
         myArray(Z, y) = 10 * Z + y
      Next y
    Next Z
End Sub

Sub Butn_Click()
  MsgBox myArray(0, 1)
End Sub

Sub testcode()
  MsgBox myArray(2, 1)
End Sub
```

First call `Main()` then call `Butn_Click()` then call `testcode()`

All appear to work.

Comment: lol typical - just testing it now to see if I can replicate the problem I was having.